# Linq query equivalent to sql

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have this code in Linq. Anybody can provide the t-sql. thanks!

```
var tsr = from t in db.Tngs
from l in t.TngUsr
from td in t.TngDepts
from u in db.Users
where t.TId == tId && u.UserId == l.UserId && u.Departments.DeptId == td.Departments.DeptId
```

is the second/third from left outer?

Comment: If you run the profiler on your SQL server instance, you can see the SQL it generates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to run that in [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/).  It would display the T-SQL equivalent of your linq code.  It would even convert that linq expression into the equivalent Lambda expression.

Comment: LinqPad is good a good option, I just need to figure out those paramaters. Also the SQL profiler has the same sql stmt.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's something like this:

```
SELECT t, l, td, u
FROM Tngs
JOIN TngUser ON TngUser.UserID = Users.UserID
JOIN Users ON Users.UserID = TngUser.UserID
JOIN Departments ON DepartmentID = tngDepartmentID
WHERE Tngs.TId = tId
```